# How do I convert double Latin letters?

Tags: javascript

How do I make sure that double letters are converted correctly? For example I want **aa** to become **2a** instead of **1a1a**.

```js
var trans = {
  "a": "1a", 
  "aa": "2a",
  "e": "1e",
  "ee": "2e",
  "o": "1o",
  "oo": "2o",
}

function transliterate() {
  var latin = document.getElementById('latin').value;
  var result = '';
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < latin.length; i++) {
    if (trans[ latin[i]] ) {
      result += trans[ latin[i]];
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
  return false;
}

document.getElementById('latin').addEventListener('keyup', transliterate);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="latin" />

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: How does this code relate to what you want to do?

Comment: @Reyno Why did you add HTML to the question? We assume it's there, but if that's not really the OP's HTML it's misleading.

Comment: @jmargolisvt I think we can pretty safely say the added HTML correctly demonstrates the code provided by the OP.

Comment: @Jamiec I'm surprised you're so willing to make assumptions considering "assume nothing" is such an important principle of debugging.  I agree, this addition is likely harmless, but it _definitely_ is not adding value to the question.

Comment: This appears to be stepping through the input letter by letter, so the currently selected single character (`latin[i]`) is never going to match 2 characters.

Comment: You need to provide exact cases. It's not a valid example. If the value is `aaVlueee` what is the expected result?

Comment: The only problem I see with this question is the lack of clarity around the expected result - as @alireza said basically. Other than that its fine

Comment: @Jamiec the problem is that a is a substring of aa and e is a substring of ee and o is a substring of oo. There is a preference to replace aa with 2a instead of 1a1a, that is, the substring is of lower priority than the longer string that contains it in the replacements.

Comment: @Jamiec but you are correct, the problem statement could be clearer. I think we can deduce it though.

Comment: @LajosArpad I got that too... and I was half way to a similar answer to yours. I think some clarity over what should happen for any other letters would have been beneficial.

Comment: @Jamiec yes, you are right. The asker seems to be a beginner. He/she seems to be unused to make a proper problem-statement. But I had that problem too when I was a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to enforce your order of priority, like here:

```js
var trans = {
  "a": "1a", 
  "aa": "2a",
  "e": "1e",
  "ee": "2e",
  "o": "1o",
  "oo": "2o",
}

let keys = ["aa", "ee", "oo", "a", "e", "o"];

function splitItems(input, index) {
    let temp = input.split(keys[index]);
    if (index + 1 === keys.length) return temp.join(trans[keys[index]]);
    let output = [];
    for (let item of temp) output.push(splitItems(item, index + 1));
    return output.join(trans[keys[index]]);
}

function transliterate() {
  var latin = splitItems(document.getElementById('latin').value, 0);
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = latin;
  return false;
}

document.getElementById('latin').addEventListener('keyup', transliterate);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="latin" />

<div id="result"></div>
```

EDIT

To be clear, the test case has this result:

[image]

Comment: The answer is not generic and is not covering what the question is looking for.

Comment: @alireza How do you get that? AFAICS, it does _exactly_ what was asked for in the question.

Comment: @alireza you can change the hard-coded input to parameters provided to a function. I have changed the input in a way that it is very similar to the code of the asker for ease of understanding. You have also stated that this answer does something different from what the question was asking for. Can you tell me how is this answer misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Your result is still the same as what question is complaining. Consider this, I want to type `aaValueee`, on `keyup` of first `a` I get `1a`. The rule is broken now, right?

Comment: @alireza nope. When you type your first a, then there is a single a in your string and there is no reason to yield 2a. When you type the second a, then the output will change the 2a. Please try typing the characters one-by-one. You will see when you type a double a, first it's shown as 1a and then, when the second a is typed and it becomes an aa, then it is a 2a.

Comment: @alireza When you type your first a, the program cannot foresee that your next character will be another a. The JS function cannot guess your next typed key. It can only work with the text already typed in.

Comment: @alireza so, if I paste aaValueee, then the result is 2aV1alu2e1e. If I type it letter-by-letter, then at the end this will be the value.

Comment: @alireza so, let me ask you a question: what should happen if a single a is typed into the textbox according to you? According to me it should yield 1a at that point. How should it behave differently according to you and why?

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes correct but what if I type `aaValueee`. What's the expected result? It's the clarity that I asked for and as long as it's not clear no answer can be correct. It may be correct but it's still based on an assumption.

Comment: I take the -1 back as the function is working well. But, I still insist on clarifying questions and making things clear before answering.

Comment: @alireza to me it's pretty clear that the result should be `2aV1alu2e1e`. The question clarifies that if there are two a characters one after the other, then 2a should be shown instead of 1a1a. To me it is clear that this is a priority to use the aa rule first and if not applicable, only then to use the a rule. And it is clear to me that the same thing is expected in the case of ee and e and oo and o.

Comment: Can't it be `2aV1alu1e2e`

Comment: @alireza no, because the aa rule takes precedence in comparison with the a rule. Since we have reason to assume that the similar problem with ee and e is consistent with the problem with aa and a, I think it's fairly safe to say that it ends with 2e1e. But, if the asker says otherwise, then I will admit that I was wrong.